# UIWebView not calling UIScrollViewDelegate methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview

In my iphone app i set delegate of my uiwebview to files owner but it is not calling uiscrollviewdelegate methods

my code is

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    NSLog(@"webViewDidStartLoad  ");
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
     NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad  ");
}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

     NSLog(@"scrollViewDidEndDecelerating  ");
}
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

    NSLog(@"scrollViewDidScroll  ");
}
```

but i am getting

```
webViewDidStartLoad
webViewDidFinishLoad
```

these messages in the console.

What is wrong with me

Thanks in advance

Comment: [This link](http://fr.ivolo.us/posts/iphone-custom-gestures-on-your-uiwebview) is exactly what you want. Or download the [custom webView files here](http://cl.ly/0K2s1m2A3u3g09032V02)

Answer (score 6):

`UIWebView`'s `delegate` property only allows you to set the delegate for the `UIWebViewDelegate` protocol. (Look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/delegate) for `UIWebView` reference.)

`UIWebView` is in itself a `UIScrollViewDelegate`, in that it receives the delegate calls from the `UIScrollView` it contains. Unfortunately, you have no API-access to that `UIScrollView`, so you cannot change its delegate; thus, it remains hard-coded to the `UIWebView` itself.

Now, there are several ways you can try and get those delegate messages.

One way for you to get `UIScrollViewDelegate` calls is subclassing `UIWebView`, if that works. In any case, you should be very careful, because depending on what you do you might break the `UIWebView` integrity and some features could stop working (possibly with some future SDK release). Furthermore, Apple discourages doing that, although it will not make your app rejected (as per many people who have reported doing that and having no problems with the App Store approval).

Another approach could be iterating through the `subviews` of your `UIWebView` until you find a `UIScrollView` object and then change its delegate.

```
UIScrollView* scrollView = nil;
for (UIView* subview in [webView subviews]) {
   if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]]) {  
      scrollView = (UIScrollView*)subview;
      scrollView.delegate = <YOUR_DELEGATE_HERE>;
      break;
   }
}
```

I am not sure if this is reliable or may break anything, since the coupling between `UIWebView` and its `UIScrollView` child is very tight and not described anywhere, but you can have a try. All in all, I don't think this is much better than subclassing `UIWebView`.

Finally, a third approach is defining your own `UIWindow` type. This will allow you to override a few key methods (`sendEvent` or `hitTest:event:`) so that you can intercept the touches *before* they are dispatched at the view level. This will give you a chance to handle them and, if required, prevent them from reaching their original target.

This is the cleanest solution, although it is more work and it will require you to define a custom `UIWindow` where you do all the touch recognizing/dispatching.

A tutorial describing how to override `sendEvent` is available [here](http://mithin.in/2009/08/26/detecting-taps-and-events-on-uiwebview-the-right-way/).

Comment: In their `UIWebview` reference, Apple says that `The UIWebView class should not be subclassed.`

Comment: Thanks, @tipycalFlow. In any case, it must be taken into account that the OP is trying to do something that is beyond what Apple allows to do; so, in that specific case, it *might* make sense disregarding Apple suggestion as to `UIWebView` override. Of course, there is no guarantee that things will work right or that they will not break in the future.

Comment: indeed, true... Also, this won't work `[webView subviews]`. [This link](http://fr.ivolo.us/posts/iphone-custom-gestures-on-your-uiwebview) talks about how to subclass the `UIWebview` correctly.

Answer (score 3):

For those that are looking after the SWIFT 3 solution:

set UIScrollViewDelegate and then here is an example:

```
var noticias: UIWebView!
noticias.scrollView.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 2):

UIWebView has it's own UIScrollView.Maybe you can try like this `self.webView.scrollView.delegate = self;`

Answer (score 0):

the scrollView of UIWebView actually has a writeable delegate property since iOS2. 
It works perfectly for me to use it.